# Comparison between Transmission Electron Microscope (TEM) to Scanning Electron Microscope (SEM)

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, microscopy

Can someone state the advantages of Transmission Electron Microscope (TEM) over Scanning Electron Microscope (SEM) and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main difference between them is that with SEM you get information about the surface using scattered electrons whereas with TEM you get information about the inner structure with transmitted electrons. TEM has higher resolution, but SEM is simpler because you do not need a thin sample.

I recommend these videos about [SEM](https://toutestquantique.fr/en/scanning-electron/) and [TEM](https://toutestquantique.fr/en/transmission-electron/). Short description of both can be also found at [this](http://blog.phenom-world.com/sem-tem-difference) webpage and in the [material for students](https://www.fei.com/documents/introduction-to-microscopy-document/) by ThermoFisher Scientific.